# "Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part" after casting

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In a SQL Server stored procedure, this CTE is being run. The summary of the problem is that the query didn't have explicit casts, but even after adding them, SQL Server still throws:

> Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "FName" of recursive query "ABC".

I've tried several variations of casting, such as using `varchar(8000)` and wrapping the `CASE` statement in a cast expression.

```
;WITH ABC (FId, FName) AS
(
    SELECT cast(1 as int), CAST('' AS varchar(max))
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        cast(B.FId + 1 as int),
        CASE WHEN LEN(B.FName) > 0
            THEN cast((B.FName + ':' +  A.FName) as varchar(max))
            ELSE cast(A.FName as varchar(max))
        END
    FROM (
        SELECT
            Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY FId) AS RN,
            FName
        FROM #T1
    ) A 
    INNER JOIN ABC B ON A.RN = B.FId AND A.RN <= 5
)
```

Executable with context:

```
CREATE TABLE #T1
(
    FId     INT
,   FName   VARCHAR(max)
)

INSERT INTO #T1 VALUES
(1, '5 Oct 2020'),
(2, '12 Oct 2020'),
(3, '19 Oct 2020'),
(4, '26 Oct 2020'),
(5, '2 Nov 2020'),
(6, '9 Nov 2020'),
(7, '16 Nov 2020'),
(8, '23 Nov 2020'),
(9, '30 Nov 2020'),
(10,'7 Dec 2020'),
(11,'14 Dec 2020')

;WITH ABC (FId, FName) AS
(
    SELECT cast(1 as int), CAST('' AS varchar(max))
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        cast(B.FId + 1 as int),
        CASE WHEN LEN(B.FName) > 0
            THEN cast((B.FName + ':' +  A.FName) as varchar(max))
            ELSE cast(A.FName as varchar(max))
        END
    FROM (
        SELECT
            Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY FId) AS RN,
            FName
        FROM #T1
    ) A 
    INNER JOIN ABC B ON A.RN = B.FId AND A.RN <= 5
) SELECT * FROM ABC
```

Comment: A [mre] will help us help you.

Comment: @Larnu I'll add it in a moment. Thanks.

Comment: The SQL you've provided doesn't replicate the issue ([db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4fa2a7617a70539bf914564bea3e8a7d)). We need a [mre] that fulfils the replicate part.

Comment: @Larnu I tried it in SSMS and it threw there. That link is already helpful. I'll look into replicating there.

Comment: Your code runs without error for me in SQL Server 2014 and 2016. What version are you trying to run it on?

Comment: @Isaac The whole thing is running on Windows Server 2019 (10.0) with SQL Server 2019 (SQL 15.0.2000.5).

Comment: That is interesting, since in rextester, this example does reproduce the problem - https://rextester.com/RGJS4919 - however it doesn't reproduce it on Sql Fiddle - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4fa2a7617a70539bf914564bea3e8a7d.

Rextester is running 2014 version and I've also tried changing the version in dbFiddle to 2014, but still db fiddle doesn't reproduce this error. On my environment (2016) this code is working.

Comment: @Cehhiro, no issues with your code on 2017 CU21. You are using RTM version of SQL Server 2019, I suspect that updating it to at least CU6 should solve the problem.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Interesting… I'll update as Roger mentioned and try again.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, that's a collation issue...

Comment: @RogerWolf this does not depend on the version but on picky typing with strings...

Comment: So you're saying that the database's default collation is different than the tempDb's default collation?

Comment: @ZoharPeled well, the cte's anchor is not picking a column. It is returning a literal string. On the other side the cte's recursive part calls a column. In this case from tempDb. If a column was declared with a certain collation, this might occur too...

Comment: @shnugo if the column was declared with a specific collation it would be more obvious... kudos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With recursive CTEs the typing is very picky, especially with strings.

The reason for the differing behaviour seems to be a difference in your server's and the column's (default) collation.

Try something along this:

```
;WITH ABC (FId, FName) AS
(
    SELECT cast(1 as int), CAST('' AS varchar(max)) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        cast(B.FId + 1 as int),
        CAST(CASE WHEN LEN(B.FName) > 0
            THEN B.FName + ':' +  A.FName
            ELSE A.FName END as varchar(max)) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT --I use one cast for the whole CASE expression
    FROM (
        SELECT
            Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY FId) AS RN,
            FName
        FROM #T1
    ) A 
    INNER JOIN ABC B ON A.RN = B.FId AND A.RN <= 5
) SELECT * FROM ABC
```